# Javascript Timer with object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I tried to make kind of object to work with my timer. The thing is when I have only bare functions (which are not in object) it is working. But When I put it inside object it doesnt work.

With this code I see only 00:01

When I used only the functions themselves it was working ok, I would like to have them in object cos I will have more functions in my code.

Thanks for help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Timer = {
    TimerID: null,
    elapsed: 0,
    changeTimer: function() {
      this.TimerID = setInterval(this.timerTick(), 1000);
    },
    timerTick: function() {
      this.elapsed++;
      var minutes = Math.floor(this.elapsed / 60);
      var seconds = this.elapsed - (minutes * 60);
      if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
      if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
      $('.timer-html').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    },
    stopTimer: function() {
      clearInterval(this.TimerID);
    }
  };
  console.log(Timer);
  $(".timer").click(Timer.changeTimer());
  $(".stop-timer").click(Timer.stopTimer());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="timer">start clock</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="stop-timer">stop clock</a>
<h1 class="timer-html">00:00</h1>
```

Comment: `setInterval(this.timerTick(), 1000);` Is wrong, it is executing `timerTick` once then passing the return value, which is undefined, into setInterval. Instead either pass `timerTick` in directly (without executing it) or wrap it in an annon function. Also be aware of context changes when using setInterval/settimeout. Either: `setInterval(() => this.timerTick(), 1000);` or `setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var Timer = {
        TimerID : null,
        elapsed : 0,

        changeTimer: function () {
           //here you need to send the delegate function without ()            //.. setInterval(this.timerTick
            //this.TimerID = setInterval(this.timerTick.bind(this), 1000);
            //arrow function variant
             this.TimerID = setInterval(()=>this.timerTick(), 1000);
        },

        timerTick: function ()
        {  
            this.elapsed++;
            var elapsed =  this.elapsed;
            var minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);
            var seconds = elapsed - (minutes * 60);

            if (minutes < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minutes;

            if (seconds < 10)
                seconds = "0" + seconds;

            $('.timer-html').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        },

        stopTimer: function () {
           clearInterval(this.TimerID);
        }
    };

    console.log(Timer);
    //here you to keep the timer context, you can use arrow function
    //.. ()=> or .bind(Timer)
    $(".timer").click(()=> Timer.changeTimer());
    $(".stop-timer").click(()=> Timer.stopTimer());
    //.bind() variant
    // $(".timer").click(Timer.changeTimer.bind(Timer));
    // $(".stop-timer").click(Timer.stopTimer.bind(Timer));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="timer">start clock</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="stop-timer">stop clock</a>
<h1 class="timer-html">00:00</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks its working, btw I saw .bind is depracted. How can I change it for smh which is not depracted

Comment: where did you read is deprecated ?
btw, I put new version which relies on ()=> ES6 sintax

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: this are 2 different API what I uses is the native bind() function of JS not the bind() API of  JQUERY, 
btw I suggest you to check out bind(), call(), apply(). These function can be handy in ES5, they have a new variant in ES6 as ()=> and ... (spread operator)

Comment: var stopWatch = {
        TimerID : null,
        startHours   : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().hours),
        startMinutes : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().minutes),
        startSeconds : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().seconds),
        totalSeconds : this.startSeconds } btw why totalSeconds is undefined? How can I access the previous variables?

Comment: GetParams.getSearchParameters is not part of your old question, 
then this is a different question, please make a new post with the code, 
you can tag my name to get help. Before to make the new question try to understand which is the context of "this" in " totalSeconds : this.startSeconds"

Comment: Hi, I made new question if u have time please check thanks

Answer (score 1):

To post my comment as an answer (was as a bit silly leaving it as a comment when i believe it solves the issue).

`setInterval(this.timerTick(), 1000);` appears to be wrong.

It is executing `timerTick` once then passing the return value, which is `undefined`, into `setInterval`.

Instead either pass `timerTick` in directly (without executing it) or wrap it in an annon function.

Either: `setInterval(() => this.timerTick(), 1000);` or `setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);`

Also be aware that setTimeout / setInterval will change the context (`this`) of the function it executes. The annon method will safeguard against that. However you could also bind the function before you pass it into setInterval.